# images are uploading on localhost but not on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to create a directory at run time on server and after that I want to save my image in that folder. So my code works perfectly with local-host but when I uploaded my website on server, the directories are not creating and the images are not uploading ?

here is my code behind

```
if (menu_photoUp.HasFile)
{
       menuNameImage = Path.GetFileName(menu_photoUp.PostedFile.FileName);                

       string sDirPath = Server.MapPath("photo_menu/" + Session["resName"].ToString().Replace(" ", "_") + "");

       DirectoryInfo ObjSearchDir = new DirectoryInfo(sDirPath);

       if (!ObjSearchDir.Exists)
       {                         
            ObjSearchDir.Create();
       }

       menu_photoUp.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("photo_menu/" + Session["resName"].ToString().Replace(" ", "_") + "/" + menuNameImage));
```

}

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have permissions to create folders and write files in the directory your website is in? Locally you are most likely an administrator and it would work fine. Once you get to the server is when you have to worry about file system permissions.

edit:

Since you are on godaddy see the following link for directions on setting up file permissions:

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/8404/setting-directory-permissions-with-windows-hosting-accounts

Comment: how would i come to know that whether i have the permissions or not ? actually I hosted my website on godaddy. now i want to create directories at runtime.

Comment: I added the link to godaddy's support with details on setting the file permissions.

Comment: actually i am new here so i dont any thing. tell me how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue while updating my personal site. I added a Wordpress icon and it worked on my local host but not after I uploaded it to the server. It was actually just a small mistake on my end - I had forgotten to add the new image to the "img" folder when updating changes via the FTP folder. It may just be a small oversight. Hopefully this helps some people out there!

Comment: Small mistakes can take hell out of you sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked a long time but may be this will still help someone.

As mentioned in the previous answers, you need to change folder permission.
In the newer Plesk control Panel, in order to change folder settings:

1. Click on the arrow button next to the folder.
2. Click 'Change Permissions'.
3. Click on the entry that is named 'Application pool group(your GoDaddy Username*)
4. You can then see it's permissions and check the box for Write permissions for this group.